# Move mouse in screen and emulater a "Click" with PURE JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, screen, pure-js

*i trying make a code pure JS* to **move mouse in screen** and **simulate a click from user**.

This **not work for me**:  `getElementBy....click(), forms[x].submit(),` etc.

**i need a function with pure js and that need: Move Mouse to x,y position in my screen. After that, using mouseEvents, "click" as a user clicking mouse.**

I tried some simulate `with key press, so KeyNumbers, "enter" with key13,` not work to me also.

Anyone knows a way to do that, without any Lib ? (i found some libs doing that, but nothing with pure JS) i am a backend enginner, so its hard to me "deep dive" in pure JS mode.

If anyone can help me , **I will be very grateful.**

if anyone can made this function to me

Comment: there is no way to move the mouse on an HTML Browser page. Only a real user in person does, for security obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons you cannot simulate user actions in the browser. But using some software on OS side is possible

Answer (score 0):

To simulate a click event take a look at [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)

```
function simulateClick() {
  // Get the element to send a click event
  const cb = document.getElementById("checkbox");

  // Create a synthetic click MouseEvent
  let evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    view: window,
  });

  // Send the event to the checkbox element
  cb.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", simulateClick);
```

However there is no `MouseEvent` to move the mouse programmatically